Lag issue using embedded font from https://use.typekit.net/
I created a web app using .net 8
I am embedding font from adobe in _Layout.cshtml using
 <link rel="stylesheet "href="https://use.typekit.net/uvj5bpg.css">

when I run the site using IIS Express the web page loads with the default font then a second later loads the adobe font from use.typekit.net . I am not sure why there is a lag. Is there a better way to load the font?
I a previous project I did the same method and there was no lag.
I tried moving the link rel to the top of the head to load first but there is still the lag issue.

Just download the css and put it on your own server.
